# Android error with login password authintication php?

Tags: java, android

Hello i am new to android development I have never seen this type of error and do not know what it means I put breaks to debug the error and it said.

04-15 00:15:37.227: E/JSON(360): **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in **C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php** on line **80**

I downloaded the xampp server didnt change anything, I have my php files stored in a folder under the htdocs called android_login_api help?

Comment: What is on line 80 of C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php file?

Comment: I didnt change the code for the xamp filed already stored but the line reads     function Config()
    {
        $this->container =& new Config_Container('section', 'root');
    } // end constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated means that the function or command should not be used anymore. If you compile your code with a newer compiler/library then what the code was written with you might get these messages.

Comment: So what compiler/library would you recommend?